# Fusing strange loops for OpenMP

Tags: c++, openmp

I have a particular set of loops for building a matrix and I was wondering if anyone knows of a way to fuse them so I can use OpenMP parallel for pragma.

```cpp
for( int i = 0; i < nbas*nchannels; ++i){
  int ket_r = i / nchannels;
  int ket_l = i % nchannels;
  for( int j = 0; j < nbas*nchannels; ++j){
    int bra_r = j / nchannels;
    int bra_l = j % nchannels;
    ...stuff_calculated...
    matrix[ i*nbas*nchannels + j ] = stuff_calculated;
  }
}
```

Each for loop walks along a dimension I need to further divide (to get variables like `ket_r`).
It looks like the loops are independent to me so I would thought this would be as simple as

```cpp
#pragma parallel for collapse(2)
for( int i = 0; i < nbas*nchannels; ++i){
  for( int j = 0; j < nbas*nchannels; ++j){
    int ket_r = i / nchannels;
    int ket_l = i % nchannels;
    int bra_r = j / nchannels;
    int bra_l = j % nchannels;
    ...stuff_calculated...
    matrix[ i*nbas*nchannels + j ] = stuff_calculated;
  }
}
```

But I get different answers. If this looks correct, I will do further investigation down this route.

I cannot provide the full code because it's part of my research group so I apologize for not posting a full working question.

Comment: Try to run your second code without any parallelism and check the answers. Then run with parallelism.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like quantum mechanics I guess :)

I suppose with different answers you mean a non-deterministic output?
And I suppose your matrix to be some kind of standard vector of ints/floats/doubles?
At first, your parallel for usage looks ok but keep in mind that the behavior is undefined for collapse-usage if the iteration limits are altered in a dynamic way via the loop executions themselves!

Without having the exact code, some further ideas:

- Did the code run fine before parallelization?
- What kind of operations are done in detail to set the matrix values? Look for possible shared dependencies there! Are further threads involved somehow?
- Ensure all variables are (correctly) initialized before used!